# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when using redux compose() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, thunk

I'm receiving this error and don't really know why, since I've copied the code from a tutorial. If I remove the compose function and just use applyMiddleware without using reactReduxFirebase and reduxFirestore, everything works correctly.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import M from "materialize-css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import firebase from "./firebase/firebase";

M.AutoInit();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase),
    reduxFirestore(firebase)
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Error log: [image]

Comment: As far as I know, use `getFirebase` only seems good based on this document => [link](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/thunks.html). Perhaps you don't need to bind `getFirestore` here.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly, this didn't work because the way to do this has changed in the newer versions and this is obsolete.